# HttpURLConnection with Parameters

Tags: java

I have a URL which I pass in that looks like this

```
http://somecompany.com/restws/ebi/SVI/4048/?Name=Tra&Brand=Software: WebSphere - Open App Servers
```

It does not like the 2nd parameter (Brand).  From a browser this querystring above works fine but as soon as I execute in Java, it fails.  When I change the webservice to accept a single parameter, then this URL works fine

```
http://somecompany.com/restws/ebi/SVI/4048/?Name=Tra
```

It seems java is having issues with the 2nd parameter.  I have tried escape characters and everything else I can think of but nothing seems to work.  Please Help!

```
String uri = "somecompany.com/restws/ebi/SVI/4048/?Name=" 
           + name+ "&Brand=Software: WebSphere - Open App Servers";

URL url;

try {
    url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
}
...
```

Comment: I'm hoping its a typo, but in your code, I do not believe you should have the string uri include "websphere-open app servers" If its not a typo, hopefully its that easy to fix

Answer (score 6):

Try **url encoding** your parameters.

Something like this:

```
String uri = "somecompany.com/restws/ebi/SVI/4048/?Name=" +name+ "&Brand=";
uri = URLEncoder.encode("Software: WebSphere - Open App Servers", "utf-8");
```

Comment: This is definitiely the way to go.  This is how I modifed it and everything now works. String query = String.format("Name=%s&Brand=%s", URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));
   
  





   try {
    url = new URL(uri + query);

Comment: confirmed. This solution works. 
But what about security problems ? can sensitive data be leak when put it in url (I am using https )?

Comment: If you're using https your parameters are encrypted. @DinhNhat

Comment: tks for kindly response , but how can i sure about that. Maybe i should try to catch https request by some tools like wireshark .

Answer (score 2):

I'd perhaps use a library that can handle HTTP parameters properly and provide suitable encoding etc. See [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) and [the tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e43) for more info.

Comment: Using a library is a good idea. You can give [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/) a try. It's very lightweight.